# Is there a Python algorithm to detect nucleii in GFP cells?

Tags: python, cell, object-detection, image-classification

I have been trying to make an algorithm that can detect the nucleii in GFP cell scans like this one:
[GFP Cell Scan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1uhX0.png)
for months. I want it to be able to output:
[desired_cell_tracking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l2MR1.png)
Is there an existing library for doing this, or is there a way to train my own basic ML classifier for this?
(I attached starter code that detects just the cell masks (but not nucleii))

```
###############################
# This code uses cellpose library to create a mask for each cell in 2 png files of GFP-channel cell scans.
###############################

#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# GFP cell detection original libraries

from skimage.io import imread
import numpy as np
import time, os, sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import fnmatch
mpl.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = 300

from cellpose import utils, io
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops, regionprops_table
import pandas as pd
from PIL import Image, ImageChops


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# GFP cell nucleii detection libraries

from skimage import (filters, measure, morphology, segmentation)
from scipy import ndimage as ndi
from skimage import data, color
from skimage.transform import hough_circle, hough_circle_peaks
from skimage.feature import canny
from skimage.draw import circle_perimeter
from skimage.util import img_as_ubyte
import cv2


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Load images

print("Libraries imported")
GFP_files = []
GFP_files.append('03152021_GFP_cells_1_lowesy_quality.tif')
GFP_files.append('03152021_GFP_cells_2_lowesy_quality.tif')
GFP_files= sorted(GFP_files)    #sorting files


plt.figure(figsize=(2,2))
img = np.array(Image.open(GFP_files[0]))
img2 = img
wid = img.shape[0]
hei = img.shape[1]


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# Detect GFP cells

from cellpose import models, io
import random

model = models.Cellpose(gpu=True, model_type='cyto')
channels = [2,0]


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
# LOOPING THROUGH FILES

#defining a null array for number of cells.
imgname=[0]*len(GFP_files)
n_cell= [[2, 0]]*len(GFP_files)
seg_masks=np.zeros((len(GFP_files), wid,hei)) #saving mask as 3d array for all images
i=-1 #for indexing

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)
print('Running...')

# THE BIG LOOP
for filename in GFP_files:
    i+=1
    img = np.array(Image.open(filename))
    masks, flows, styles, diams = model.eval(img, diameter=30, channels=channels)

    n_cell[i]= [filename,np.max(masks)]
    seg_masks[i,:,:]= masks
    imgname[i]=[filename]


    im = np.copy(img[:,:,0])
    im[masks==0]=0      #set main background threshold on
    # 'im' now is a single-color-channel image that only has one of the cells in it, everything else is background.
```

Comment: If you can isolate cells the you are halfway there.  You should be able to extract the region of a cell, then do thresholding and identification of circular regions. Your biggest problem is that nucleii can be bright or dark depending on whether they are above or below the focal plane.  Have you looked at taking multiple images at the same X-Y coordinates but at different Z-levels?  With three or more images you can begin to use convolution filters to improve the cell and nucleaus boundries.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I will use circle detection. Is there any way to smoothen the brightness level in an image so it has level brightness all throughout-do you know?